# Avalonedit How to invalidate Line Transformers

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, avalonedit, invalidation

I've added a LineTransformerClass that is derived from DocumentColorizingTransformer to the TextEditor:

```
TxtEditCodeViewer.TextArea.TextView.LineTransformers.Add(new ColorizeAvalonEdit());
```

Is there any programmatic way of invoking invalidation on the Linetransformer?

I've readily assumed that since it is added to the textview, the following should work:

```
TxtEditCodeViewer.TextArea.TextView.InvalidateVisual();
TxtEditCodeViewer.TextArea.TextView.InvalidateArrange();
TxtEditCodeViewer.TextArea.TextView.InvalidateMeasure();
```

But they don't. Just in case, I've tried the following as well:

```
//TxtEditCodeViewer.TextArea.TextView.InvalidateVisual();
//TxtEditCodeViewer.TextArea.TextView.InvalidateArrange();
//TxtEditCodeViewer.TextArea.TextView.InvalidateMeasure();
//TxtEditCodeViewer.InvalidateVisual();
//TxtEditCodeViewer.InvalidateArrange();
//TxtEditCodeViewer.InvalidateMeasure();
//TxtEditCodeViewer.TextArea.InvalidateArrange();
//TxtEditCodeViewer.TextArea.InvalidateMeasure();
//TxtEditCodeViewer.TextArea.InvalidateVisual();
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The text view maintains a cache of the generated visual lines. Forcing WPF to repaint the control just makes it re-use the results in the cache and does not call your line transformer again.

You can use the `TextView.Redraw` method to invalidate the cached visual lines:

```
textEditor.TextArea.TextView.Redraw(segment); // invalidate portion of document
textEditor.TextArea.TextView.Redraw(); // invalidate whole document
```

This works for both `ElementGenerators` and `LineTransformers`.

For `BackgroundRenderers`, it is not necessary to invalidate visual lines. Instead, just tell the text view to invalidate the layer to which your background renderer belongs:

```
textEditor.TextArea.TextView.InvalidateLayer(this.Layer);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I set the backgroundcolor of some text...

So i had to do a Workaround, before set background (the background is saved in the cache):

```
if (Txtpreview.TextArea.TextView.LineTransformers.Count > 2)
{
    Txtpreview.TextArea.TextView.LineTransformers.RemoveAt(1); // removes selection highlight
}
Txtpreview.TextArea.TextView.LineTransformers.Add(new MarkSameWord(Txtpreview.SelectedText));
```